# String Splits with Regex

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I need help with regex to split up strings in my log line.
Log message as follows:

> Token1|Token2|Token3|Token4|Token5|Token6|Token7|key1=abc key2=89042683 keytransport=tcp keyUrl=POST /b/opt/ HTTP/1.1::~~Accept: */*::~~Content-Type: application/octet-stream::~~Connection: Close::~~User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0)::~~Host: something.su::~~Content-Length: 185::~~Cache-Control: no-cache::~~::~~|\330\302\037\262\220\333J;\242.\031z0x\334\177L keyType=web

Given the following:

```
message = "Token1|Token2|Token3|Token4|Token5|Token6|Token7|key1=abc key2=89042683 keytransport=tcp keyUrl=POST /b/opt/ HTTP/1.1::~~Accept: */*::~~Content-Type: application/octet-stream::~~Connection: Close::~~User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0)::~~Host: something.su::~~Content-Length: 185::~~Cache-Control: no-cache::~~::~~|\\330\\302\\037\\262\\220\\333J;\\242.\\031z0x\\334\\177L keyType=web"
hash = {}
hash['T1'], hash['T2'], hash['T3'], hash['T4'], hash['T5'], hash['T6'], hash['T7'], message = message.split /(?<!\\)[\|]/
```

It splits the **keyUrl string** yielding the following in `message` truncating the payload and subsequent key values in the log file:

> key1=abc key2=89042683 keytransport=tcp keyUrl=POST /b/opt/ HTTP/1.1::~~Accept: */*::~~Content-Type: application/octet-stream::~~Connection: Close::~~User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0)::~~Host: something.su::~~Content-Length: 185::~~Cache-Control: no-cache::~~::~~

I've been trying various permutations of regex patterns but stumped and was wondering if anyone could help with a better pattern than `message.split /(?<!\\)[\|]/` Many thanks.

**Edited**The result that I'm aiming for is:

```
puts hash
{"T1"=>"Token1","T2"=>"Token2","T3"=>"Token3","T4"=>"Token4","T5"=>"Token5","T6"=>"Token6","T7"=>"Token7",}

puts message
key1=abc key2=89042683 keytransport=tcp keyUrl=POST /b/opt/ HTTP/1.1::~~Accept: */*::~~Content-Type: application/octet-stream::~~Connection: Close::~~User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0)::~~Host: something.su::~~Content-Length: 185::~~Cache-Control: no-cache::~~::~~|\\330\\302\\037\\262\\220\\333J;\\242.\\031z0x\\334\\177L keyType=web
```

Hope that helps to clarify and many thanks again for the attempts to assist.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're just doing a split on |. You can just do this: `...split("|")`. You can gather the remaining bits like this:

```
...,hash['T7'], *messages = message.split("|")
messages
=> ["key1=abc key2=89042683 keytransport=tcp keyUrl=POST /b/opt/ HTTP/1.1::~~Accept: */*::~~Content-Type: application/octet-stream::~~Connection: Close::~~User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0)::~~Host: something.su::~~Content-Length: 185::~~Cache-Control: no-cache::~~::~~", "\\330\\302\\037\\262\\220\\333J;\\242.\\031z0x\\334\\177L keyType=web"]
```

If want the whole string after Token7| you can join them together like this:

```
message = messages.join("|")
=> "key1=abc key2=89042683 keytransport=tcp keyUrl=POST /b/opt/ HTTP/1.1::~~Accept: */*::~~Content-Type: application/octet-stream::~~Connection: Close::~~User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0)::~~Host: something.su::~~Content-Length: 185::~~Cache-Control: no-cache::~~::~~|\\330\\302\\037\\262\\220\\333J;\\242.\\031z0x\\334\\177L keyType=web"
```

EDIT: now if you print it out

```
puts message
```

you get:

```
key1=abc key2=89042683 keytransport=tcp keyUrl=POST /b/opt/ HTTP/1.1::~~Accept: */*::~~Content-Type: application/octet-stream::~~Connection: Close::~~User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0)::~~Host: something.su::~~Content-Length: 185::~~Cache-Control: no-cache::~~::~~|\330\302\037\262\220\333J;\242.\031z0x\334\177L keyType=web
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your example text simplified somewhat:

```
text = "Token1|Token2|Token3|key1=abc key2=89042683 no-cache::~~::~~|\\330"
```

It is my understanding that you want the following:

```
hash = {}
hash['T1'], hash['T2'], hash['T3'], message = text.split('|')
  #=> ["Token1", "Token2", "Token3", "key1=abc key2=89042683 no-cache::~~::~~"] 
hash
  #=> {"T1"=>"Token1", "T2"=>"Token2", "T3"=>"Token3"} 
message
  #=> "key1=abc key2=89042683 no-cache::~~::~~"
```

Please let me know if my assumption is incorrect.

Edit: In view of your comment, is it more than:

```
hash['T1'], hash['T2'], hash['T3'], message, keyurl = text.split('|')
  #=> ["Token1", "Token2", "Token3",
  #    "key1=abc key2=89042683 no-cache::~~::~~", "\\330"]
```

or

```
hash['T1'], hash['T2'], hash['T3'], *messages = text.split('|')
  #=> ["Token1", "Token2", "Token3",
  #    "key1=abc key2=89042683 no-cache::~~::~~", "\\330"]
messages
  #=> ["key1=abc key2=89042683 no-cache::~~::~~", "\\330"]
```

that you want?

Comment: Hey Cary, I actually need the keyUrl to keep all it's value in entirety and also whatever key-value pairs that proceeds after it. So the first portion of your assumption is correct that ultimately the first few splits are tokenized into the hash, but the subsequent key value pairs will remain in the message array. P/S: that's where the keyurl containing |\330\.. is stumping me and tokenizing the subsequent keys.

Comment: I made a small change, but if I still don't understand the question, it will have to wait until this evening...

Comment: Thanks Cary, I've updated the post above with the intended result set. Again, appreciate your help and have a good rest of the day. Cheers.

Comment: Expected outcome for the message array as follows;

messages #=> [key1=abc key2=89042683 keyUrl=POST...no-cache::~~::~~...|\330... keyType=web]